# Does every subvariety of $\Bbb C^n$ have a smooth point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic subvariety of $\Bbb C^n$.

Is it true that $X$ always admit a smooth point and if it is, how can one prove it ?

Comment: See Theorem I.5.3 in Hartshorne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", Chapter I, Theorem 5.3, the set of singular points of any variety is proper closed subset. Hence by this theorem, X has a smooth point.